# APT - Webmin DEB source website not connecting

Tags: apt, connection, webmin

I am currently trying to perform `apt update`, everything works great until it reaches webmin...

It's hung on `0% [Connecting to download.webmin.com (108.60.199.109)]`.

Does anyone have any insight or advice?

Comment: I noticed all of their downloads are now through Sourceforge (prdownloads.sourceforge.net). Could this be the problem, their old (download.webmin.com) no longer exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still an issue as of today, Thursday 26 October  14:22:37 AEST 2017.

EDIT: **Back online as of Thursday 26 October  15:48:02 AEST 2017**

```
Err:21 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
Could not connect to download.webmin.com:80 (108.60.199.109), connection timed out
```

It appears to be a complete website subdomain outage as per http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/download.webmin.com.html

I will keep updating this answer with any changes. Sorry for the bad news.

**HUNG PROCESS?** - The process is waiting to timeout on the source DEB URL, just leave apt running eventually it will timeout and continue the `apt update` process. Not ideal but at least you can still update.

Comment: yap .. still down

Comment: At least it’s free